# django - pass multiple instance into form and save it in DB

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a view where they are multiple posts and I want when the user like one of them, the form take the user_id and the post_id and save it into the DB. This is th Models.py:

```
class LikePost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.user.username, self.post.name)
```

Forms.py:

```
class LikePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LikedShops
        fields = ['user', 'post']
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'post': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

Views.py:

```
def posts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LikePostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save(commit=False)
            u.user = request.user
            u.save()
            return redirect('posts')
    else:
        form = LikePostForm()
    context = {
        'posts': Posts.objects.all(),
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "posts.html", context)
```

and this the form in posts.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <article class="card mb-4">
            <header class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title"><b>{{ post.name }}</b></h4>
            </header>
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 150px;" class="card-img" src="{{ post.image.url }}"/>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
            </div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <form action="/posts/" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ l_form|crispy }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Like</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

        </article><!-- /.card -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my edit, I did what you said, I made changes to:

forms.py:

```
class Meta:
    model = Liked
    fields = ['user', 'post']
    widgets = {
        'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'post': forms.HiddenInput()
    }
```

posts.html:

```
<form action="/posts/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="post" value="{{ post.pk }}">
      {{ l_form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Like</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def posts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        l_form = LikePostForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if l_form.is_valid():
            u = l_form.save(commit=False)
            u.post = Posts.objects.filter(pk=l_form.cleaned_data.get('post')).first()
            u.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Form is valid!")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'Form is not valid! {request.POST}')
    else:
        l_form = LikePostForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'post': Posts.objects.all(),
        'l_form': l_form
    }
    return render(request, "posts.html", context)
```

Now when I click the Like button, I got this message `**Form is not valid! <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['cNk9ZDS33Nj0l95TBfwtedL1jjAbzDSrH15VjMNZAcxjQuihWNZzOkVnIyRzsjwN'], 'post': ['1', ''], 'user': ['1']}>**`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback.

Comment: Not directly related but you have a typo here: `Pots.objects.all()`

Comment: @Selcuk how can I do it please ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

---

First, the `__str__()` method should return a string and not a tuple

```
class LikePost(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.user.username, self.post.name)
```

---

Second, there is a typo; change `Pots` to `Posts`:

```
context = {
    'posts': Posts.objects.all(),
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, "posts.html", context)
```

---

And third and last, the line `u.post = request.post` is throwing the error you mention, because the `request` object has no attribute `post`.

So change your form code to add the post in hidden state (I used `fields` instead of `exclude`):

```
class LikePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LikePost
        fields = ['post', ]
        widgets = {
            'post': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

and then change your view:

```
form = LikePostForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    u = form.save(commit=False)
    u.user = request.user
    u.save()
```

---

After edit to the question:

Try adding `post.pk` as a hidden input in your form:

```
<form action="/posts/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="{{ post.pk }}">
    {{ l_form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Like</button>
</form>
```

or you can also do in your view:

```
u.post = Posts.objects.filter(pk=form.cleaned_data.get('post')).first()
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, the solution you have gave me I already done it but the probleme is that the form is not saved in the DB, I don't understand why. When I click Like, everything is good but in the DB it's not added. How can I save it in the DB directly ?

Comment: @F.F when you look at the posted data (`print(request.POST)`), does it contain the correct `user_id` and `post_id`?

Comment: @F.F oh, I just noted something else: did you exclude the fields in the form on purpose (`exclude = ['user', 'post']`) ? Or did you intend to use `fields = ['user', 'post']` instead?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['wGwn97vARhADndqcUjtFJ1FkeUexVqxIZ8uS4Pqr3tjrVcZDjuqN88KGGN4R8HfQ']}> this is what I got when I print the request.POST
I have 2 foreign key in my model, the first one is the user and the second one is the post, but it only give me the user

Comment: I exclude them so that they want we seen in the form, do I have to add them as fields ? but I only want the submit button to be seen

Comment: @F.F see my updated anser; use the widget `forms.HiddenInput()`

Comment: I have done exactly what you said but still it doesn't work, the form is empty, how can I fill both the fields with the username and post.name ?
when I print the request.POST this is what I have : <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['e3QKab7deXrLvxoPYwe2de0XUw1uN7dVzP2d8dl6FTjHfo0lx2FxbozkA2ZaTsZS'], 'user': [''], 'post': ['']}>
As you can see, the fields are empty, I can get the user by request.user but the post is still empty

Comment: @F.F Right, you need to assign the post. Also, how do you know which post is rendered together with the `LikePostForm`? Is it just one post per page (then it probably is a URL parameter) or are there multple posts on a page (then each one will probably have a hidden ID field or something similar)?

Comment: please see the edit I made to my post, I have multiple posts on the page, and when I add the hidden field of post_id and then make **u.post = from.cleaned_data['post_id']** it gave me error as it should be an instance.
I have tried several solutions, none of them have worked. I think i'm gonna change the 'post' in model from ForeignKey to CharField that's the only solution I can think of

Comment: I tried your solution but still got a problem: the form is not valid. Please check my edit

Comment: @F.F you can inspect the errors by using `print(form.errors)`; that should tell you what the problem is.